# ltrace not showing library calls

Tags: command-line, 19.10

I am using Ubuntu 19.10. `ltrace` is not showing library calls.

This is the output of 2 commands I tried:

```
vipin:/home/vipin/Videos$ ltrace ls -l 
total 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

```
vipin:/home/vipin/Videos$ ltrace -c ls -l 
total 0 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.000000                     0 total
```

---

```
vipin:/home/vipin/Videos$ ltrace -V
ltrace version 0.7.3.
Copyright (C) 1997-2009 Juan Cespedes &lt;cespedes@debian.org&gt;.
This is free software; see the GNU General Public Licence
version 2 or later for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty.
```